# IE not setting cookies (Firefox and Chrome works fine)

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, microsoft-edge

For some reason Microsoft Edge (IE 10 and 9 tested as well) are not setting domain cookies for one of my applications. The same code seems to work fine on other browsers. What could possibly be wrong with my code or should i assume this has got to do with my hosting provider settings? By the way I am using Plesk for Hosting my application. See attached screenshots of Fiddler for both Edge and Firefox.

Edge - Login Screen
[image]
Edge - Cookie for managerId is not set and login fails.
[image]

Firefox - Login Screen
[image]
FF - Cookies set (all 3) and login successful.
[image]

**UPDATE** : Code (Bare bone structure)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onLoginSuccess() { 

    parent.window.location.href = '/Manager';
}
function validateLoginForm() {
    var res = $('#frmLogin').valid();
    if (res) {
        $('#frmLogin').submit();
    }
        return false;
}
</script>

<form action="/Home/login" class="cd-form" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="onLoginSuccess" data-ajax-update="#loginError" defaultbutton="btnLogin" id="frmLogin" method="post">                                                                
<p class="fieldset">
    <label>E-mail</label>
    <input id="emailId" name="emailId" placeholder="E-mail" type="text" value="" />
</p>
<p class="fieldset">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" />
</p>
<p id="loginError" class="field-validation-error"></p>
<p class="fieldset">
    <input class="full-width" type="submit" value="Login" id="btnLogin" name="btnLogin" onclick="return validateLoginForm();"/>
</p>
```

We are making a Ajax request via a popup (whose code is shown above) to verify login credentials and then set cookies for user. While the same code is working in Firefox and Chrome, it does not (as can be seen via fiddler snapshots) in Edge browser.

Comment: are these cross domain(or port) ajax requests?

Comment: on the same domain and yes requests are ajax based.

Comment: Can you share a reduced code sample that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Please see my updated question for code. After we validate user input and make ajax request to controller (i inherited the code from someone else), we do standard off-the shelf authentication/authorization calls with minor tweaks for client needs. You can see the website LIVE at gopromanager.com and try the login on the website. I can share more details via email/chat. TIA.